# .htaccess redirect Urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I´m creating a new Wordpress Website based on a old one.

Both sites got an archive page but with different permalinks.

```
Old-Adress:   old.url.com/anzeigen/anzeigen-detail/article/article-name123.html

New-Adress:   new.url.com/anzeige/article-name123
```

Since I have 2000+ articles, I´m looking for a single redirect Rule to handle all of them at once.

I know how to do a simple redirection for a single URL but not multiple at once.

Comment: If you want to use plugin there is plugin exist for this activity. https://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/ and also you can write own rules in `.hraccess` which you want to use ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 the page is a part of a multi-domain project which handels all their redirects within the htaccess therefore I have to stick to it.

Comment: Is the difference `/anzeigen/` vs `/anzeige/` a typo in your question?

Comment: @MrWhite no, it should be like that

Comment: So, `/anzeigen/anzeigen-detail/article/` is static/fixed text in all URLs? And `article-name123` is the only _dynamic_ part?

Comment: @MrWhite yes /anzeigen/anzeigen-detail/article/ is always the same in all URLs and article-name123 should be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^anzeigen/anzeigen-detail/article/([\w-]+)\.html$ https://new.example.com/anzeige/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the old URL `/anzeigen/anzeigen-detail/article/article-name123.html` does not exist at the new domain, then you don't necessarily need the preceding condition.

`[\w-]` - The dynamic part (ie. `article-name123`) can consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid any caching issues.